# Visual Studio 2005 Search Memory

Tags: c#, visual-studio, search, memory

I don't think this exists, but I'll throw this out there anyway.  Is it possible, while debugging, to search for a value in memory?

For example, if I have a string "uniqueString" cached somewhere in memory, but I don't know under which variable it's stored--can I do a search for it?  As in, find out which variable(s) have "uniqueString" as their value?

This is for C# managed code.

Answer (score 4):

windbg will let you do the search directly. 's' is the command you're looking for, here's a very good [cheat sheet](http://www.software.rkuster.com/windbg/cmd.htm). sos extension lets you scan for string objects too in managed code though the s command should find them too (must use unicode aware search).

Answer (score 2):

You have the same functionality in Visual Studio, [available](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171363(VS.80).aspx) from the immediate window. Although, you'd have to manually somehow limit the address range to search in (see the syntax in the link).

(edit) BTW, you can easily create dumps from VS too: Debug->Save Dump As.

Comment: That link seems dead, do you know where that documentation might now live?

Comment: @user833970 this feature is dead: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8a77490d-846d-4b5b-9462-35a3e8a788eb/memory-search-in-immediate-window?forum=visualstudiogeneral

Comment: that's unfortunate, but thanks