# Is "search memory" in Visual Studio 2008/10's immediate window broken?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

In Visual Studio 2005, I came to rely heavily on MSVC's Immediate Window for [its useful  search-through-memory-for-byte-patterns feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171363(v=VS.90).aspx). We've recently upgraded to VS2010, and now that `.S`  command doesn't seem to work any more. For any search I try, even when I directly copy-and-paste [the examples from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171363(v=VS.100).aspx), I always get the following error when I try to use the memory search:

> CXX0014: Error: missing operand

[Others have reported this problem here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/475300/visual-studio-2005-search-memory/3668708#3668708), but Google doesn't turn up any useful discussion. Is this feature simply broken in MSVC2010? I get the feeling that Microsoft doesn't much value native code in their MSVC series, so it wouldn't surprise me.

Windbg still supports this feature (I hope), but I'd rather stay within MSVC's more comfortable debugging environment if possible.

Comment: Use connect.microsoft.com to report this.  Only way to get it fixed in the next service pack or release.

Comment: I just tried it with VS2010 and all the examples on MSDN worked fine for me.  I am using VS2010 Premium 10.0.30319.1.

Comment: @Hans : I wish! We reported actual code generation bugs in 2005 that continued to pop up in 2008.

Comment: Tough to be on the bleeding edge.  Microsoft supports that too, you can get a 'partner' kind of relationship.  You'll get to talk to the devs directly, you won't have to find some soul on an Internet web site to help you out.  Pretty simple that get that going, it just takes money.

Comment: @Hans Sad to say but we actually are in the partner program already, but the usual turnaround we get for even major "the compiler just emits wrong code in this for loop" issues is months. Going through channels, even just to ask "is XYZ still working?" takes forever.

Comment: These kind of details are *very* important to mention in your question.  When you got the ear of the guys that can fix this and cannot get this done, there is (usually) very little you can accomplish by asking for help at a site like this.  We don't get to fix the product.  At best you are asking for 'who else is annoyed'.  Odds are *very* low here, connect is the best place.

Comment: @Hans : True enough. What I was hoping to learn here was "does this work for anyone else?", because after all I might just be doing it wrong. Thus, I haven't asked MSFT about this issue yet -- I wanted to check to see if I just had some silly misconfiguration issue locally before I headed over to Redmond.

Answer (score 2):

No, the command is not broken in general.

Just trying with a dummy project of my VS 2010 Express install, `.S` command *does* work.