# how to search for a string in memory while debugging?

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio-2010, debugging, search

I am trying to search for a string in the memory of a program I am debugging with visual studio 2010. I am trying to use the Immediate Window to do this but whenever I try 
(.S -A 0x400000 0x400200 "MyString") It gives me the error 
"CXX0014: Error: missing operand" and I am not sure why it does or how to fix it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903532/is-search-memory-in-visual-studio-2008-10s-immediate-window-broken (sorry for the duplicate vote since the link is for C++, but it might be helpful anyway)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I right understood you are searching for a `string` value (suppose some runtime value) among all values available in your program during the run. If so, I don't think it's even possible, not that I'm aware of, from `Visual Studio`. There are always `hacking` solution for that, like dump process memory, read assembly, but even there you can met problems, if (just an example) the program (at this point I suppose it wasn't written by you) store the values in `SecureString`.

If this is not your intention, please clarify.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171363(v=vs.100).aspx
That is how you search memory, but when I try to do it in the Immediate Window I get the error "CXX0014: Error: missing operand" I am trying to figure out why I get the error and how I can fix it so it searches.

Comment: @IanLundberg that link specifically says at the top its for C++ applications