# search for a string in memory in immediate window

Tags: c++, visual-studio, immediate-window

I'm trying to use the immediate windows in C++ at runtime.
The Relevant documentation in MSDN is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171363%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

[image]

I saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9777790/how-to-search-for-a-string-in-memory-while-debugging) also. But is is not yet solved and related to C#.

Comment: Don't post pictures of text. Post the text.

Comment: I'll have to guess that you are using VS2015.  It has a new native debugging engine, the legacy Windbg style commands are pretty broken.  Tools > Options > Debugging > General > tick the "Use Native Compatibility Mode" option to revive it.

Comment: @HansPassant , I'm using VS Professional 2013

Comment: Always select the VS version you use when looking at MSDN documentation.  That VS2013 is not listed is not an accident.  It also has a new debugging engine, the one that supports the new natvis visualizers.  But not the option to fall back to the legacy engine.  Bummer.  Use Windbg.

Comment: MSDN: "This option is valid only for C++ projects in runtime mode."

Comment: @ZDF; Am I not in runtime mode when debugging ?

Comment: @HansPassant , thanks, I guess I'll do without it.

Comment: @user2346536 I am not sure on the exact meaning of MSDN comment. It seems to refer to a kind of project, not to a state. The comment is not present on ".K (Display Callstack)" help page. If you go to Immediate Window and enter `>S`, a list with available commands will pop-up. `S` is not among them, therefore I believe that it was removed. `K` works.

Comment: @user2346536 Maybe Microsoft was unable to fix problems like [this](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/845091/debugging-memory-search-command-in-immediate-window-is-broken-with-large-values) and decided to remove it (notice the status).